# All http header keys coming as lower case in ConnectionRequest.headers of Autobahn websocket server

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, autobahn, autobahnws

Why does autobahn web socket server change all http header keys to lower case? I need to implement authentication token in header with OAuth2 standard with custom header 'Authorization:Bearer $token'. But it seems from autobahn 'request.headers' in onConnect method of WebSocketServerProtocol class all the keys are changed to lower case. What is the reason behind this? Can I use 'authorization' instead of 'Authorization' as the key to fetch auth token from request in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2), "HTTP header ... field names are case-insensitive." In your example, any of the following incoming header spellings are equivalent: "Authorization", "authorization", "AuThOrIzAtIoN".

The software in question lower-casifies the header to make lookups easier. You should always use the lower-case version as the key.

Comment: Thanks @Robᵩ for the quick reply.